# UICollectionView - scrolling not inside, but in whole screen

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, snapkit

I'm building my first app in Swift. I have `RestaurantViewController`. Half of the screen is filled by restaurant name, description, logo, atd.
And under this I have `UICollectionView()`, filled with restaurant Coupons. Everything works fine, but I wanna disable scrolling INSIDE the `CollectionView`, and allow to scroll in entire page - so when user scrolls in coupons, whole page is scrolling down and next coupons are showed.

How can I do it?

[IMAGE - Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTyUg.png)

[IMAGE - I wanna this after scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rnrg.png)

Coupons are loaded via API, so they are available few moments after setupUI() etc.

My code inside setupUI():

```
...
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
self.couponsCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
couponsCollectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CouponCollectionCell.reuseIdentifier)
couponsCollectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
couponsCollectionView!.isScrollEnabled = false
...
```

I am not using Storyboard, just all programmatically. Also with UIKit and SnapKit (external library)
My SnapKit code for create constraints in screen:

```
...
couponsCollectionView!.snp.makeConstraints { make in
   make.top.equalTo(couponsTitle.snp.bottom).offset(0)
   make.left.equalTo(0)
   make.width.equalToSuperview()
   make.leading.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
}
...
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Any reason you're not building the rest of the UI as their own collection view cells?  You could make the 'Restaurant' and 'Coupon' labels section headers and put whatever you want in their respective collection view cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with adding the content top of UICollectionView as a header and rest as cells of UICollectionView

An example is as follow

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let headerHeight: CGFloat = 300.0
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = 50.0
    var data = []

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        return collectionView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        collectionView.register(DataCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DataCell")

        collectionView.register(HeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderView")
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2 
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return section == 0 ? 1 : data.length
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderView", for: indexPath) as! HeaderView
// do some stuff here
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DataCell", for: indexPath) as! DataCell
// Do some stuff here in your cell
            return cell
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

       // Calculate dynamic height
        let dynamicHeaderHeight = xxx;
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: indexPath.section == 0 ? dynamicHeaderHeight : cellHeight)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return section == 0 ? CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: headerHeight) : CGSize.zero
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But.. My ViewController has many view elements like 10x UILabels, 2 UIImageView, 2 UIStackView, atd.. interactively connected together, so there is no one "RestaurantView" and then "CouponsCollectionView", is there any way how to put wrap these parts together in one Header?

Comment: Ofc, You can create a HeaderView in which you can create all these components and update your logic inside the view e.g https://www.kodeco.com/21959913-uicollectionview-tutorial-headers-selection-and-reordering try this, shows images as to how to do it

Comment: It works with HeaderView, thank you man! :) One more question.. my header has dynamic height depends on content (some restaurants have "bonus program", etc.).. How can I set in collection view, that height of Header is dynamic and not strict 300px? Thank you!

Comment: @JiříKřenek i have updated the code , you can update the dynamic height in collectionViewLayout . If you feel this question has helped you please accept the answer and upvote :)

Comment: Thank you! But, I dont know exactly how to calculate dynamic height. Thats why I am trying to do it dynamically, like based on the content of the header view cell. Is there any option how to doit? Like calculate cell viewContent's height and use it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add the restaurant information (logo, name, ...) inside a UICollectionViewHeader so everything scrolls smoothly, as suggested by @clawesome and @Muhammad

Following your approach and if we try to achieve the desired effect without using a header to include the restaurant information, I created a very simple project to simulate the behaviour.

Instead of constraining the collection view at the bottom of the restaurant information, you could pin it to the top, and update the contentInsets and add the necessary padding. Like this you achieve the same effect as it was starting just under the restaurant information.

Then you could implement `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` and update the constraints of the restaurant information according to the amount the user has scrolled.

```
 private func configure() {
    view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: addLayout())
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
    
    restaurantView = UIView()
    restaurantView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    restaurantView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    view.addSubview(restaurantView)
    
    restaurantViewAnchorConstraint = restaurantView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        restaurantViewAnchorConstraint,
        restaurantView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        restaurantView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        restaurantView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        
    ])
    
    collectionView.contentInset.top = 200
    collectionView.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets.top = 200
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = collectionView.contentOffset.y
    restaurantViewAnchorConstraint.constant = -(200 + offsetY)
}
```

`200` is the height of the restaurant information view and the restaurantViewAnchorConstraint is a `NSLayoutConstraint` declared as a property as:

`var restaurantViewAnchorConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`

Remember to first add the collection view as a subview, not after the restaurant information, if not the collection view will hide all this information.

[Video proof](https://imgur.com/a/E2BQtiS)